# How to display new object field in trigger error page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

I need to show the value of the fields of the objects being created on the error page. i tried to do it via add error but it doesn't output dynamic data

```
trigger checktime on Appointment__c (before insert, before update) {
    Time startDate;
    Datetime endDate;
    String Name;
     
    //Fetch all appointment records to compare
    List<Appointment__c> listOfAllAppointments = [SELECT Id,Appointment_Data__c,Appointment_Data_End__c,Doctor__c
                                                  FROM Appointment__c];
                                                  
    for(Appointment__c newAppointment : Trigger.new) {
        for(Appointment__c appointment : listOfAllAppointments) {
            if(appointment.Appointment_Data__c <= newAppointment.Appointment_Data_End__c
                && appointment.Appointment_Data_End__c >= newAppointment.Appointment_Data__c
                && appointment.Doctor__c == newAppointment.Doctor__c) 
            { 
              //  newAppointment.addError('Your Error Message'+newAppointment.Doctor__r.Name);
              
             newAppointment.Appointment_Data_End__c.addError('Bad');
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work".

Comment: i need to display in error page newAppointment.Appointment_Data_End__c but it doesen't work.

Comment: You have simply reiterated your vague description of *"it doesn't work"*. Please describe ***specifically*** what behavior you observe and how it differs from your desired behavior using an **[edit]** to your post.

Comment: i add new description

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't output dynamic data"?  Please [edit] your post to give a specific example of what you want to output and the actual value that is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for your error is that relationship fields are not implicitly part of the trigger context:

```
newAppointment.addError('Your Error Message'+newAppointment.Doctor__r.Name);
```

`Doctor__r` is a relationship from the lookup field `Doctor__c`

If you need to output Doctor names in the error message, you will have to query for these before the for loop that generates the `addError`. This needs to be a bulkified query and will look something like this:

```
Map<Id,Doctor__c> doctorsById = new Map<Id,Doctor__c>();
for (Appointment__c appt: Trigger.new) {
   doctorsById.put(appt.Doctor__c,new Doctor__c());
}
doctorsById = new Map<Id,Doctor__c> ([SELECT Id, Name FROM Doctor__c
                                         WHERE Id IN: doctorsNyId.keySet()]);
... rest of your trigger

   newAppointment.addError('Your Error Message'+ 
                            doctorsById.get(newAppointment.Doctor__c).Name);
```